# Add addtional test for files

Tags: command-line, batch-file

What would I need to add, to also ignore file names containing AppData with .exe extensions? I am using this in an SetupComplete.cmd for unattended Windows setup, and have AppDataLocal.exe and AppDataRoaming.exe which are sfx archives and do not want these deleted. I am hoping this can be a wildcard, something like AppData*.exe.

```
forfiles /p "%WINDIR%\Setup\Files" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c for %G in (@path) do @if /I [%~xG] neq [.reg] @echo del /F /Q %G" /d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to use FORFILES - it is quite slow.

I would do something like the following:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /s /a-d "%WINDIR%\Setup\Files"^|findstr /rive "\.reg [\\]AppData[^\\]*\.exe"'
) do del "%%F"
```

I pipe a recursive DIR /B through FINDSTR, using a pair of regular expressions to exclude file names that end with ".reg" or "\AppData*.exe", ignoring case. The result is iterated via FOR /F so I can delete each file.

Comment: Thankyou @dbenham. I tried running this script, but it deleted everything.

Comment: @Schmitty - I can't imagine why it didn't work for you, as I tested and it worked perfectly for me. Are you sure you had .reg and AppData*.exe files to start with? Are you sure you copied the script properly? For testing you could put ECHO before DEL until you get the correct results.

Comment: Yes, I ran the script from %WINDIR%\Setup\Scripts. And had hkut.reg and AppDataRoaming.exe in %WINDIR%\Setup\Files\winrar, and it deleted everything, except the winrar directory.

Comment: @Schmitty - I tested again with the exact setup as you described, and it worked perfectly. I added `@echo off`, and `/a-d` to suppress folder names, but that should not have any impact on the end result.

Comment: is the /a-d switch on dir or del command?

Comment: @Schmitty - It is exactly as I have it in the edited answer - on the DIR command. The change should have no impact on the final outcome, other than changing what appears on the screen (no echo of commands and no error message trying to delete a folder).

Comment: I can not figure out for the life of me, why this is not working the way it should.

Comment: Apologies, I had to refresh the page to see the edit.

Comment: I figured it out. I was doing some searching online, and found the same sample you gave me, except for /vire instead of /rive.

Comment: @Schmitty - `/vire` and `/rive` are equivalent. They are both shorthand for  the following four options: `/r /i /v /e`, meaning "Regular expression", "Ignore case", "reVerse logic (print lines that don't match)", "match pattern against End of line".